# Incompatible element type Profile for collection of Id

Tags: apex, soql

What is wrong with my SOQL query on profile?

It's saying "Incompatible element type Profile for collection of Id"

What do I need to change

```
    global class ProductAction {
    WebService static String convertToService(Id product) {
        string result; // Return a string telling us if this worked or not
        Id currentProfile = UserInfo.getUserId(); // Get the current user profile Id
        Id CurrentUser = UserInfo.getUserId(); // Get the current user Id

        Set<Id> allowedProfiles = new Set<Id>(); // Create a new set to profile Ids
        for (Profile p: [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'System Administrator']) {// Get the System Administrator profile
            allowedProfiles.add(p); // Add them to the set
        }

        Set<Id> allowedUsers = new Set<Id>(); // Create a new set to store User Ids
        for (User u: [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Id = '005w0000004j93kAAA' OR Id = '005w0000004Noi6']) {//Select Joy Palmer and Andy McGregor Id's and select Jeremey Sharp and Mark O'Leary once they're in SF}
            allowedUsers.add(u);// Add them to the set
        }
        Product2 prod = [SELECT Convert_to_Service_catalogue__c, R_D_Service_Owner__r.id , Project_Owner__r.Id From Product2 WHERE Id = :product]; // Get the product

        if( //If...
            (currentUser == product2.R_D_Service_Owner__r.id) || // They own it
            (currentUser == product2.Project_Owner__r.id) || // They own it 
            (allowedProfiles.contains(currentProfile)) || //They're a system admin
            (allowedUsers.contains(currentUser))// They're a specific user
            ) {
                //Do stuff!
                prod.Convert_to_Service_Catalogue__c = true;

                UPDATE prod;

                result = 'Success!';

            }   
        else {// Otherwise...
              // Do nothing
              result = 'Go Away!';
            }  
           // Return a message
           return result;
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've created a `Set<Id>`, so you need to add just the Id values to set, not the entire record:

```
Set<Id> allowedProfiles = new Set<Id>();
for(Profile p: [...]) {
    allowedProfiles.add(p.Id);
}
```

You also need to do this for the user records later (using `u.Id` instead of `u`).

Also, in the if statement, you used `currentUser == product2.R_D_Service_Owner__r.Id`, which should be `currentUser == prod.R_D_Service_Owner__c` (change your query as well), as well as the Product_Owner__r.Id comparison.

Comment: No need for a loop!

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, you are doing wrong assignment here.

`Id currentProfile = UserInfo.getUserId(); // Get the current user profile Id`

and later, in the `if` block you are comparing `(allowedProfiles.contains(currentProfile)`

Now `allowedProfiles` contains `Set<Id>` of `'System Administrator'` profile